# Change css of external website in realtime

Tags: javascript, css, dom

I know this is a completely novice question, but I honestly have no idea.

I want to create a page that has a form asking for a URL and when someone enters their URL and clicks submit, it loads their page but with my own CSS changes added to it in real time.

I know it probably has something to do with DOM? But I'm not sure. If someone could point me in the right direction/tutorial/google search, I'd be so grateful!

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe if you can come up with a set of rules like I what a css framework does but instead of using class names as selectors, use actual html elements and style. Now, when your user enters the url, gather all the HTML on the server side, and send the html page with your css stylesheet. Be careful to strip out any Javascript code that comes along with the HTML or handle it in a way you think it suitable. If the user enters a malicious url which comes with it own malicious script then your application may be facing some serious threats.

Comment: "Now, when your user enters the url, gather all the HTML on the server side, and send the html page with your css stylesheet."

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2):

The only way you're going to be able to do this is to proxy all of the content server-side from your domain, while inserting your CSS.  This is not an easy task for a novice.

I would consider writing a browser extension instead, where you have fewer security restrictions to worry about.

Comment: How would I do that? Here's a website that kind of does what I want to do for reference http://wonder-tonic.com/geocitiesizer/.

Comment: @DanielleSchechter, Yes, the are doing exactly what I said... proxying content.  Basically, the content doesn't come from the original site or server.  Look at the URL and you will see that.  How you go about this depends on what you have installed server-side.  PHP?  Ruby/Rails?

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I'm familiar with PHP just never done anything with Proxy, DOM, etc. I'm starting from scratch so I can build in any language. I was just looking for a base point.

Do you have any suggestions for google searches for this?

Thanks so much for your help/patience!

Comment: @DanielleSchechter The first thing you have to do is fetch the remote markup.  You can do this with cURL, or simply use one of the fopen wrappers to get it for you.  Then you want to use DOMDocument to load the HTML and change all links to point to the version of the URL on your site.  How you handle resources like images and scripts is up to you.  I recommend not proxying those and leaving them as-is.  Finally, with DOMDocument, inject a reference to your new CSS.  All you have to do then is output the HTML to the client.